# Embedding JAudio package in java program

Tags: audio, feature-extraction

Yeah Guys;
I am doing a final year project (BSc) on how Content Based music analysis (Music Genre classification and similarity measures) can improve the song selection of Media player’s shuffle function. 
I would like to embed JAudio to perform the Feature Extraction.  I downloaded the package from: sourceforge.net/projects/jaudio/ and I am using the instruction illustrated at http://jaudio.sourceforge.net/jaudio10/embedding.html . However, I am encountering a few problems:

1. Using the class Batch the instruction say use
   setFeatures(java.io.File[] files) or setFetaures(RecordingInfo[]
   files) . However, according to the API at
   http://jaudio.sourceforge.net/jaudio10/javadoc/index.html THERE ARE
   NO SUCH METHODS.
2. The next step is Batch.exectue(). However this throws a Null Pointer Exception.
3. Also when I try to use the GUI, the file chooser (add recordings) does not load the file (a .wav)

I would really like to use JAudio in my project.  However, because of the above reasons I am not able to. Firstly, I was wondering if Any one had tried embedding JAudio and had the same problem.If not, does anyone know of an alternative program of package that extracts similar features?

---

I would to thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to add recordings, you should use -Xmx to enlarge the JVM memory that jAudio can use.
I encountered the same question several months ago, it seems Cory Mckay does not provide API for embedding.I read the source code of jAudio and I found that it's not so hard to understand, you can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance with me I suggest you to use Ecilipse where you need to import that jaudio libraries in it.
Because as far as my knowledge concern it is been made in Purely JAVA with use of swing component so you can directly execute it...
It is good one among all Music tool for feature extraction procedure so Go with it.
If any further query just post it in comment.

Answer (score 0):

setRecordings(File[] files) is what you are looking for.

However, this version is old and produces output to default file locations in your working directory. XML is not a common format these days and Weka format went out of style more than a decade ago. If this is a problem, you may need to upgrade.

Likewise, the default feature set is 10+ years old. The new set is much more useful for most common timbre based problems. You might not like the performance with these defaults.